# Mongo query in nested object of object

Tags: mongodb

I am using spring and mongo data JPA. I have a document which has following nested structure
[image]

I want to search all the documents where any one of the `renderMap.propBindings._class = "packagename.classname"`. How do I do this?

I tried -

```
{renderMap: {$elemMatch: {propBindings: {$elemMatch: {_class: "packagename.classname"}}}}}
```

and

```
{renderMap.propBindings._class: "packagename.classname"}
```

But it didnt work.
Thanks

Comment: You have another object between propBinding and _class starting with "j8m0...". So that the reason your solution didnt work

Comment: So, both my renderMap and propBindings are HashMap, so I will have lots of keys inside propBindings which are decided on runtime. So what needs to be done to fix this. Thanks

Comment: if the key is dynamic, then difficult to query. Can you tell your scenario?

Comment: I am saving Java Hashmap<String, Binding>, where Binding is object that implements an interface. I need to refactor all my model classes into another sub-project so they can be reused. Now all the objects saved in this hashmap have new classname. I need to modify them in mongo, so that they work with new code (since I am using spring's Mongo Pojo jpa). I forgot to apply @TypeAlias annotation, else this problem could have been avoided.

Comment: Is there an aggregation I can perform? There will be a few records with such data, like not more than 20-30, so I can update manually. But number of total records is more than 300, so I can't search manually.

Comment: Im thinking of, why you keep `j8m0...` object since you won't deal with it. If there is an array, you can use `propBinding` as an array. So you can easily perform array operators to get

Comment: I have to deal with it on code level. Mongo is just a storage for my class objects. I need those keys for O(1) access in my code. I can't change the object structure, its too late for that, for me. :D